# How would you implement a Generic view with the authenticated user as the context object?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Lets say I have a custom route `/some-route` with no url params so it won't have `/some-route/<user-id>`.

I want to create a generic view that will use the authenticated user as the context object.  This is how I would do it, but I figured there might be a better way to do it.

```
UserDetail(DetailView):

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```

The biggest problem I can think of with this is that its expecting a pk kwarg to be past from the route.  I don't want specify any route args though.  Any ideas?  Ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggested class will work fine.

```
class UserDetail(DetailView):

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```

It is the detail views `get_object` method they expects the primary key to be a named argument in the url pattern. This isn't a problem, since you've overridden it.

One other suggestion would be to use the `LoginRequiredMixin`, so that users can only access the view when they are logged in.